# How do I position my logo right at the center of menu/navigation?

Tags: css

Need all of your help regarding this matter. I'm currently stuck at this css positioning were the logo should be right in the middle of the menu navigation just like this website http://theorydesign.ca/ .... that's what i am trying to achieve.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Position</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<style>
body { 
  font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  color:#000;
}
.container { 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
 }
#header { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 96px; 
  position: fixed; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4; 
  z-index:9999;
}  
#logo { 
  width:76px; 
  height:64px; 
  display:block; 
  position: absolute; 
  left:50%; 
  margin-left:-43px; /*I'm not sure if this is the right assigned value for this. Don't know the number/value that i should assign*/
  top:15px;
} 
#logo a { 
  background:url(logo.png); 
  display:block; 
  width:76px; 
  height:64px;
}
#menu-left { 
  width:256px; /*This is just the number/value that I assign based on the size of my screen*/
  left:50%;
  top:24px; 
  margin-left:-350px;
  z-index:3;
}
#menu-right {
  width:256px; /*This is just the number/value that I assign based on the size of my screen*/
  right:50%;
  top:24px;
  margin-right:-350px;
  margin-left:0;
  z-index:3;
}
.menu {
  position:absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin:0;
}
.menu li {
  float:right;
  margin-left:65px;
  line-height:35px;
  margin-bottom:0;
  position:relative;
  list-style:none;
}
#menu-right li {
  float:left;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:65px;
}
.menu  li a {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.menu  li a:hover {
  color:#999;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="header">
   <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html"></a>
   </div>
   <ul class="menu" id="menu-left">
    <li>
     <a href="#menu1">Menu1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#menu2">Menu2</a>
    </li>
   </ul>        
   <ul class="menu" id="menu-right">
    <li>
     <a href="#menu3">Menu3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#menu4">Menu4</a>
    </li>
   </ul>    
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please clean up your html/css sample and make it more readable?

Comment: Clean up your code or create a fiddle for this. You can't expect someone to format your code for you before they fix it.

Comment: hope you guys understood the code now. sorry for the last post, it's my first time to post here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that they are using a navigation container then setting the margin of the text off the center.  The lines are an image as well as the logo.  The links are li that are adjusted by the margin.  To create this effect start by creating a container that has a margin of auto and a set width.  Float the text to the left or right of the center.  Once you have the text worry about the image placement.  There isn't one way to accomplish this.  You can use html/css, jQuery, etc.